# prove that C* has $\phi(n)$ elements of order $n$ for every $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove that for each positive integer $n$, C* ( group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication) has exactly $\phi(n)$ elements of order $n$ .  Do we need to prove it by induction? If yes, what is $\phi(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

- $\phi$ is [Euler's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function):
  it counts how many positive integers less than or equal to $n$ are relatively prime to $n$.
- The elements of order $n$ satisfy $z^n=1$.
- Find all solutions of $z^n=1$.
- Choose the ones of order $n$.

If you get stuck, do it first for $n=12$.

Comment: Don't know about OP. But this post specifically the last pointer is enough for the insight to approach this problem. +1.